# Wifi router bridging

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

My primary router is HG 8247 Huawei ONT Device with primary gateway 192.168.100.1. I want to extend its range using a TPLink WR740N i have lying around. I have done the following without success:

- First method was a wireless link between the two routers. Set Tp-link to WDS bridging mode and set its default gateway to within the Huawei range i.e. 192.168.100.2. Disable DHCP on Tplink. In this way  only one device my laptop is able to connect to the TPlink at one time and access internet. Smartphone doesnt connect to Tplink as it stops at getting ip address.
- The second method was to connect two routers using ethernet cable. I tried both the WAN LAN ports of the TPlink and with and without DHCP disabled (and with/without changing ip address) but I couldnt simply access internet when i connected to TPlink wifi.

Any ideas as to what to do now? Is it a limitation of Huawei?

The WR740N can work this way as many tutorials show but in my case the configuration isnt working.

Comment: Why did you set Tp-Link's primary gateway to 192.168.100.2? Shouldn't it be 192.168.100.1?

Comment: Why would I make it conflict with the Huawei address

Comment: I think you are confusing what a gateway is. A gateway is a device with highest position within the network. That means, all devices connected to it send their packets to it. The devices can be connected by cable, or by Wi-Fi. You should read some info on this on Wikipedia: [Gateway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gateway_(telecommunications)) [WDS Bridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_distribution_system)

Comment: What would the difference in ip addresses achieve basically

Comment: Now I know what do you mean. Set up the Huawei like a normal Wi-Fi router and then set up the Tp-Link wi-fi router in WDS mode disable DHCP, NAT and other stuff. That should be it. You should check the IP addresses of the smartphone and the laptop (if they are not the same, if they are not set as static). Oh, is DHCP server on the Huawei turned on?

Comment: What's the specific model of the TPlink? I assume you purchased a wireless extender. 2nd, what's the ip address for the Huawei? Looking at the Huawei manual, I didn't see anything for supporting WDS. In order for WDS to function, it has to be supported by both devices. I didn't see anything in Huawei manual about WDS options. As an alternative, you purchase a wireless range extender. This will act like a second wireless hotspot without the need for WDS configurations. As an example: http://www.on-networks.com/products/extenders/default.aspx.  This is what I use with my router to extend range.

Comment: @Tim its not a repeater. Generic router

Comment: I understand Delta,Based on what you're using,  my suggestion was to utilize a repeater(wireless extender) as the Huawei manual doesn't appear to show any support for WDS in that model. You need WDS on all devices to make the distribution work. Here's the quick and dirty guide to WDS. http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/wireless/wireless-howto/31191-everything-you-need-to-know-about-wireless-bridging-and-repeating-part-1-wds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flashed router with OpenWRT to make it a repeater.

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  Could you expand your answer a little to elaborate for other users who may have a similar question?

Answer (score 0):

Connect both routers to your home switch via cat5.  Setup both routers to not issue DHCP  (or use one only, if you have no in-house server to do so).  Configure both as access points using the same SSID, but - and this is the key - on different and non-overlapping channels (ie: ch 1 and 6, 6 and 11, etc).  Now, your devices can hope from one to the other as required.

A good link to read more on this can be found [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/104469/how-to-extend-your-wi-fi-network-with-simple-access-points/).  The channel spacing diagram shows it all.

Secondary router must be set to use primary router as default gateway.
I.e. Primary router IP is 192.168.100.1
Secondary Router Ip is 192.168.100.2 with it's default gateway set to 192.168.100.1.

This is necessary to route internal traffic out to the internet pipe(cable,dsl Modem) from the secondary router.

Comment: Unfortunately that is for Tomato routers and the settings dont match with my router therefore I cant apply those settings